# Regarding scattering region calculation

Tags: siesta, scattering

I am doing scattering region calculation when I checked the output file of scattering region calculation i got warning like this

Begin: TS Checks and Warnings
Electrode Left will not update cross-terms or local region.
Electrode Right will not update cross-terms or local region.
End: TS Checks and Warnings

What does it means

is it a serious warning or should i carry calculation forward

Thankyou.

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but have you got an answer from elsewhere over the last few months? Are you still actively in need of an answer to this particular question? Please update us!